# Google Maps API not working in release version

Tags: android, google-maps

Here there are two google_maps_api.xml one for release and one for debug.I have the same API key in these two xml files.But Debug is working.Only signed APK is not working.How can i solve the issue

Comment: You have to regenerate the map key using the same process for the signed apk.

Comment: I think the API key should not be the same in the two configs. The SHA-1 fingerprint is different, as you're signing the two builds with different certificates. You can read about it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en

Comment: Generate SHA1 key using your keystore and place this SHA1 key in google developer console

Comment: Yeah I have done that,the new key is the one which i am using when i run with the new key in debug its working.Only in signed apk its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are signing the release apk, you're probably doing it with a different keystore. You should add the SHA1 of that key to the API Console just as you did with the debug version.